# App crashes on starting new activity in emulator as well as in real device

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

when I start a new activity but app crashes with following error.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                          Process: com.food.sheenishere.stark, PID: 9976
                                                                          java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.food.sheenishere.stark/com.food.sheenishere.stark.home}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                                                                           Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                                                                              at com.food.sheenishere.stark.home.onCreate(home.java:84)
                                                                              at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
                                                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
```

**home.java**

here below somewhere error lies . This is a part of code of home activity . after sign in when I try to open this activity but the app crashes with the error shown above.It was working earlier fine but suddenly it crashes on virtual device as well as real device.

```
public class home extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference category;
    TextView txtFullName;


    RecyclerView recycler_menu;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Category,MenuViewHolder> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("Menu");
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        progressDialog.show();


        //init firebase
        database=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        category=database.getReference("Category");




        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               Intent cartIntent = new Intent(home.this, Cart.class);
                startActivity(cartIntent);
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        //set name for user
        View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
        txtFullName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtFullName);
        txtFullName.setText(Common.currentUser.getName());
```

Comment: post your activity_home.xml please

Comment: Maybe post your xml files, my guess would be that R.id.txtFullName is not found in the layout R.layout.activity_home but instead is inside of a separate xml that you are pulling the headerView from. So it should be 'headerView.findViewById(R.id.textFullName);

Comment: @Devsil it worked thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following code.

```
txtFullName = (TextView)headerView.findViewById(R.id.txtFullName);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try following code.

```
txtFullName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtFullName);
```

Instead of this line use below

```
 txtFullName = (TextView)headerView.findViewById(R.id.txtFullName);
 txtFullName.setText(Common.currentUser.getName());
```